# How do I change the fact that pip is installing to the wrong copy of python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I used `pip` to install a script, named `stdlib_list`:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Sam>python -m pip install stdlib_list --user
Requirement already satisfied: stdlib_list in c:\users\sam\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (0.5.0)
```

Note that `stdlib_list` installed to a folder named `python37`

I have checked the path that Windows is using.

[image]

Note that the environment variable `path` points to `Python38-32`, which is not `python37`

What gives?

### Edit:

Output of Windows `where pip`:

```
C:\Users\Sam>where pip
C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe

C:\Users\Sam>
```

and `pip -V`:

```
C:\Users\Sam>pip -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\program files\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: what does it say when you type `python -V` or `pip -V` in console?

Comment: You can do `<pythonExecutable> -m pip install yourPackage` to install for a specific version. This saves you messing around with your versions of python & environment variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credit for this answer goes to [byxor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5601284/byxor), who left their answer as a comment, instead of an answer:

On the Windows command line, type:

```
C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe -m pip install stdlib_list
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using the pip version installed in Python38-32, not python37.

To change it, ensure that your command `python` in a terminal points to the correct python installation, and it'll install for the correct version.